# spring data mongodb and jpa transaction

Tags: mongodb, jpa, spring-data, entitymanager, rollback

I have 2 entities that needed to be persisted in two different DB's:

1) MyClassMetaData - persisted on mysql via jpa+hibernate in spring (entityManager)

2) MyClassRawData - persisted on mongoDB via spring data (mongoTemplate)

There is a one To one Relation between the two entities:
There is no meaning for only one entitiesto be persisted without the other.
there will always be a metadata AND rawdata for each save.

My service for saving these 2 entities looks like this

```
@Transactional
public void saveMyClass(metadata, rawdata){

 // Do Something here
 this.entityManager.persist(metadata);
 this.mongoTemplate.save(rawData);

}
```

My question is: how do i make sure that if an error occurs on this save method - a rollback will take place and for both classes?

thanks

Comment: you can use a ChainedTransactionManager il you use MongoDb v4.0.x, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794472/7861603

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want to achieve: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mongo.cross.store.html
However it ties the two entities strictly together.

Comment: This has been removed in Spring data 2.0. I have the same problem, and don't know how to handle it.