# Spring Boot MongoRepository @Rollback for tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, rollback, mongorepository

I wrote a Test for a MongoRepository in Spring Boot, and the test works fine. The only problem is that when the test is over, I want a rollback, so that there will be no change in the database caused by the test.

```
// package...

// imports...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MetistrafficApplication.class)
@Rollback(true)
public class AppRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private AppRepository appRepository;

    @Test
    public void insertTest() {
        App app = new App("test");
        App appInserted = appRepository.save(app);

        assertThat(appInserted.getName(), equalTo(app.getName()));
    }
}
```

I put @Transactional before @Rollback, but get this error:

```
java.lang.illegalstateexception:Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test for test context
```

When I searched for the error, I couldn't find any code with MongoRepository. So, how can I solve this?

EDIT: After adding `@Transactional("PlatformTransactionManager")`, the error I get is changed to this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'PlatformTransactionManager' is defined: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'PlatformTransactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
```

Comment: normally Spring rollback every transaction after executing a test method. Add `@Transactional` on your class and delete `@Rollback`. This should work.

Comment: I still get the same error: failed to retrieve ....

Comment: try to use `@Transactional("PlatformTransactionManager")`

Comment: the error I get is changed, I edited the question, please look at the end.

Comment: Which TransactionManager do you use? Hibernate? If yes than try with `@Transactional("hibernateTransactionManager")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an implementation of Spring's TransactionManager for MongoDB since it is not transactional in the ACID sense. So no, you cannot use @Transactional annotations with MongoDB and you'll have to do all the cleanup manually or else use DBUnit and add your own extensions for MongoDB.

EDIT:
As [Petter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739524/4657798) mentioned in his answer, starting with MongoDB 4.0, MongoDB has [support for ACID transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) and you can find the [official SpringData examples on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/transactions) and also have the [feature's release post](https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data) in Spring's developer blog

Comment: I guess I will accept this until a better solution shows up :(

Comment: You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386449/spring-data-and-mongodb-simple-roll-back-with-spring-within-transactional), although you'll get the same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use @Transactional with mongo. Take a look at this example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-transactions

You'll need mongo 4.0. Also need to enable mongo replication (`mongod --replSet rs0`)

Then you'll need to add this bean to your spring application

```
@Bean
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

This is enough to use `@Transactional` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use try catch block. Its better if you can avoid try catch. Anyway if you need to rollback you can do it like this.

```
 TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```